# Is this a Bug in Wix Bootstrapper command line?

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper, burn

I already posted a related problem here:  [Wix: Managed BA command line not effective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989084/wix-managed-ba-command-line-not-effective), which is about command line passed during upgrade.

Now I tried to explore, how it interpret the command line. Here is my run method to do so:

```
protected override void Run()
{
  string cmdOptions = string.Empty;
  this.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Launching custom TestBA UX");

  Debug.WriteLine("Command.Display: {0} Command.Action: {1}", this.Command.Display.ToString(), this.Command.Action.ToString());
  Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

I understand that Wixdba would digest its own command line options and would pass extra to our Managed Bootstrapper Application. From above mentioned post, this line from log:

```
[1A44:1E54][2014-02-24T17:47:22]i301: Applying execute package: {f1d57671-5e3d-4be7-908f-5a47e72737d9}, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f1d57671-5e3d-4be7-908f-5a47e72737d9}\BootstrapperSetup.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f1d57671-5e3d-4be7-908f-5a47e72737d9}\BootstrapperSetup.exe" -uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade'
```

shows that it is passing -uninstall and -quiet to BootstrapperSetup.exe which is in cache i.e. already installed there.

Here are the results of command line options passed to Bootstrapper:

> C:\bin\Debug>BootstrapperSetup.exe -quite -uninstall

**Command.Display: Full,  Command.Action: Uninstall**

> C:\bin\Debug>>BootstrapperSetup.exe -q -uninstall

**Command.Display: None  Command.Action: Uninstall**

> C:\bin\Debug>>BootstrapperSetup.exe -q -u

**Command.Display: None  Command.Action: Install**

**Summary:** From above test, it seems that

1. -quite is not effective, while -q does.
2. -u is not effective, while -Uninstall does.

Although, after knowing this, I can parse for -quite and -u in my Managed Bootstrapper, but I would like to know, **If it is a Bug or I'm doing something wrong here**.

Best regards

Comment: -u might not be supported at all. Could you point to the documentation of the version you are using?

Comment: ahan.. I picked 'quite' from the log file generated during upgrade, that's what I never passed. And so haven't consult any documentation. However, on wix-users mailing list, I read about these command line arguments as well.

Comment: I guessed -u as it is responding to -q instead of -quite..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug.  You must spell quiet correctly, it's not 'quite'.  I believe the intent for the command line was to accept what msiexec would accept.  msiexec does not use -u for uninstall (or anything as far as I can tell), but -q is used.

Unfortunately, the documentation on this is not very good.  You'll have to read the WiX source code for a lot of things like this.  You will find exactly what the engine will parse for you at src/burn/engine/core.cpp (the ParseCommandLine method).

Comment: I picked "quite" from log file generated during upgrade. That command line is being generated via base bootstrapper.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed You mean the line that you copied into your question, which has the correct "quiet" and not "quite"?

Comment: ahh... my bad.. you are right, it is quiet... How dumb I am... arrrrrg.
You know, its not easy to be a Non-English... :)